# How to write C# based CLI-based APP to use new Microsoft "Terminal" application

Tags: c#, command-line-interface, tty

I have an application that uses a custom control to implement a faux CLI interface (looks and works superficially like a powershell/CMD window). I've spent a fair amount of time developing this control, but it's implemented via a custom RichTextBox with multithreaded functions controlling and parsing the inputs. Needless to say, since it's not written in native C++, it's prone to being fairly slow and somewhat clunky and this  is causing some significant frustrations. While this was happening, Microsoft began development on a new means of interacting with similar applications via a generic CLI application they're calling "Terminal".

Reference:

> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-windows-terminal/
>
> https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

This looks amazing, and I'd greatly prefer to use this interface instead of the one I've got and just leave processing the inputs themselves to my app. Unfortunately, I haven't understood, or been able to locate, the means by which the "Terminal" application communicates with a particular back end application.

Can someone please give me some pointers as to where I should look / what I should look for, so I can research this? The choice of "Terminal" as the name of this application has, for obvious reasons, made Googling for this information tremendously difficult, not the least because I'm currently unaware of what *specific* API/tech terms I should be using to narrow down the results and the documentation on GitHub seems all to (reasonably) pertain to development of the Terminal app itself, as opposed to how to interface / interact with it.

Thanks!

Comment: You interact with it the same way you interact with the normal Windows Console.  You run command line applications in it.

Comment: I didn't downvote.  Also, the answer is largely the same.  Cmd interacts with it by calling WriteConsoleOutput (or some similar API), just like it does for the normal console.

Comment: My understanding is that C# Console applications run in the context of the CMD shell from which they are instantiated. I don't WANT that, I want MY application to run in its OWN context, merely using the Terminal application as the front-end. I don't want *any part* of CMD.

Comment: That's only true if you launch them from cmd.exe.  It's entirely possible to launch them with some other process (Explorer is the obvious example, when you double click on a CLI application).  Terminal can launch different executables as well, it comes with examples to launch powershell, cmd, and the azure cli, adding another one requires editing it's configuration file right now.

Comment: From my reading, the old, legacy CMD and PS interactions between the front end and the back end went through something called "IOCTL". The new system is apparently supposed to abstract this process so that the backend can be *anything* instead of specifically targeting CMD (or PS). So how would you tell a C# Console application to address the Terminal mechanism and NOT just attach to the existing CMD architecture that it's always used?
Reference: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-inside-the-windows-console/

Comment: You can interact directly with the Terminal's Console with their APIs, they have some examples on their [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal/tree/master/samples)